# Edit dictionary values if keys found in list

Tags: python

Is there a cleaner way to do this? Could I accomplish this via list comprehension?

```
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'twofoo': 'twobar', 'threefoo': 'threebar'}
some_list = ['foo', 'threefoo']

for key in data:
    for item in some_list:
        if key==item:
            data[key] = 'randomfoo'
```

I want to clean the values from a dictionary
so 'random foo' will always be the same

Care to elaborate on the downvotes?

Comment: if you want to check if a key is in dictionary, you can do `key in data` . And do `data[key]` to get value

Comment: Will `'randomfoo'` be constant?

Comment: Show the desired output.  I believe data is missing a `:`

Comment: What does `# some action` entail?

Comment: Random foo is constant @vaultah

Comment: # some action literally changes the value of the item to a constant @khelwood

Comment: @BorkoKovacev consider uncommenting the "randomfoo" line. The comment suggests that it's a placeholder for another, maybe more complicated action.

Comment: @AnandSKumar No, I want to check if keys in data overlap the keys in the list and if they are, modify the value.

Comment: you don't need the outer loop , just the inner loop and changing condition to `if key in data:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the intersection of the dictionary keys with the list, and update values at those keys:

```
for key in set(data).intersection(some_list):
    data[key] = 'foobar'

print(data)
# {'twofoo': 'twobar', 'threefoo': 'foobar', 'foo': 'foobar'}
```

You could also define your list as a set and do a quick membership check (with *O*(1) complexity) for each key:

```
some_set = {'foo', 'threefoo'}

for key in data:
    if key in some_set:
        data[key] = 'randomfoo'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
res = {key: 'randomfoo' if key in some_list else value for key, value in data.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
{'twofoo': 'twobar', 'threefoo': 'randomfoo', 'foo': 'randomfoo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
data = {'foo': 'bar', 'twofoo': 'twobar', 'threefoo': 'threebar'}
some_list = ['foo', 'threefoo']

for key in data:
    if key in some_list:
        data[key] = "randomfoo"

print(data)
```

Output:

```
{'foo': 'randomfoo', 'twofoo': 'twobar', 'threefoo': 'randomfoo'}
```